# Trying to Print Gridster Items to PDF without overlapping contents

Tags: gridster, angularjs-gridster

I want to print gridster items  to pdf using chome browser. Unfortunately the item overlaps on next page. Is there any way to make gridster item go to next page if it doesnt fit in the current page when printing to pdf?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzNTN.png)